# More control over Dialogflow's date period

Tags: date, dialogflow-es, period

I'm trying to get Dialogflow to report sales in different time periods. When I ask things like

- what's the sale last month
- what's the sale in march 2011

They work fine. However, if I didn't specify "last" or year, Dialogflow always think I'm asking about the upcoming period (which I guess works great for restaurant booking, etc.). For example, "what was our sale in april" would guess that I mean April of next year.

Should I write a fulfillment to deal with this or is there a way to specify only historical periods only?

Another related question is it has trouble understanding notations like 2010q1 or q2/2015 which is quite common in economics and finance. "q1/2000" would extract only q1 (correctly, but with the upcoming q1). "2000q1" wouldn't be recognized at all.

Thanks!

Comment: You can create an entity to handle the "year" specifically.

Comment: Right. I just thought that this might be something Google already have built in.. `@sys.date` for example you can choose `$date.recent`

Comment: Okay. Is your problem solved?

Comment: Not really. Guess I'll have to parse it myself.

Comment: Okay.. tell me if you need any help regarding this.

Comment: Maybe this would help other people. Just found out that suppose you have entity named `yourdateperiod`, with value `$yourdateperiod`, you could add another entity with value `$yourdateperiod.original` and get that from the request ^^